# How to know if a number is in another number python

Tags: python, numbers

I have a list:

```
numbers = [12, 23, 26, 54]
```

I need know if each pair of numbers have at least 1 digit in common. For example `12` has the digit `1` and `2`, so the pair (12,23) should be included since they both have the digit `2`. I would like to have the list of pairs returned.  For example

```
>>> numbers = [12, 23, 26, 54]
>>> function(numbers)
[(12, 23), (12, 26), (23, 12), (23, 26), (26, 12), (26, 23)]
```

Here is my code so far

```
pari_his=([12, 23, 26, 54])
par=set()
parus=[]
b=list()
c=list()
resitev=list()
for i in pari_his:
    i=str(i)
    for e,j in enumerate(i):
        if e%2==0:
            b.append(j)
        else:               
            c.append(j)
print(b,c)
for ena, dva in zip(b, c):
    kuku=(ena,dva)              
    parus.append(tuple(kuku))
print(parus)
for juj in parus:
    print(juj[0],juj[1])
```

Comment: 1. What have you tried yourself? 2. Can you provide (preferably multiple) inputs and their expected outputs?

Comment: so you want to know which numbers in the list have a certain digit?

Comment: >>> numbers([12, 23, 26, 54]) <---- input 
{(12, 23), (12, 26), (23, 12), (23, 26), (26, 12), (26, 23)} <---output

Comment: Downvotes are coming because you're not showing any of your efforts here. What can we help you with? Coding for you?

Comment: srry just add my program srry didnt want to look like a dick but yeah im stuck and dont know how to do it

Comment: Your code's naming makes no sense, and it's also not clear from your question what you want to accomplish. And given the low effort you've put into communicating, I don't think it's salvageable.

Comment: well yeah my naming is weird cuz im making my code in my laguage.But the guy below solve it :) so its ok :) i tryed to make it clear srry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `itertools.product` to get the tuples (you will have to filter out the same number twice), then use `set` intersections of the digits to see if they have any digits in common.

```
import itertools
numbers = [12, 23, 26, 54]
[t for t in itertools.product(numbers, numbers) if set(str(t[0])) & set(str(t[1])) and t[0] != t[1]]

[(12, 23), (12, 26), (23, 12), (23, 26), (26, 12), (26, 23)]
```

without `itertools` you can just build the tuples yourself.

```
numbers = [12, 23, 26, 54]
[(i, j) for i in numbers for j in numbers if set(str(i)) & set(str(j)) and i != j]

[(12, 23), (12, 26), (23, 12), (23, 26), (26, 12), (26, 23)]
```

Comment: thx for that but i dont understand how this works if anyone can do this whithout intertools it would be grate

Comment: @user3433946 updated example without using itertools